# db.submitchanges() not working

Tags: sql, entity-framework, datacontext

I  am having problem submit changes using  submitchanges method. It is working fine on all tables except zone table.
table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ZONE](
    [zcode] [varchar](30) NOT NULL,
    [Zone_name] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [Mode] [char](1) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_ZONE] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [zcode] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

code:

```
private void AddZoneButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            BillingDataDataContext db = new BillingDataDataContext();
            ZONE z = new ZONE();
            z.Zone_name = this.ZoneNameTextBox.Text;
            z.zcode = this.Zonecodebox.Text;
            db.ZONEs.InsertOnSubmit(z);
            try
            {
                db.SubmitChanges();
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Comment: what behavior is being presented on AddZoneButton_Click? are you getting an error? Nothing happening?

Comment: I'm not getting any error and that is a big problem.

Comment: Have you confirmed that the event handler is even being called?

Comment: lol yes i have confirmed it. and also checked it with breakpoints  that all data is loaded correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Tried `db.ZONEs.Add(z);` instead of `db.ZONEs.InsertOnSubmit(z);`? Perhaps post some more information on which EF you are using. And are you sure that the object is actually filled?